# Multiple joins involving same table produces "column doesn't exist" error - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm new to joins and I'm sure this is ridiculously simple. 
 If I remove one join in the query the remainder of the query works regardless of which join I remove.  But as shown it gives the error saying the column doesn't exist.  Any pointers?

```
select 

loc_carr.address1 as carr_addr1,

loc_cust.address1 as cust_addr1


from db_name.carrier, db_name.customer

join db_name.location as loc_carr on vats.carrier.location_id=loc_carr.location_id

join db_name.location as loc_cust on vats.customer.location_id=loc_cust.location_id
```

thanks

Comment: any pointers? Yes, show your query please.

Comment: -1 Please share some stuff. A code or something that helps us with the situation. Cheers

Comment: select 

loc_carr.address1 as carr_addr1,

loc_cust.address1 as cust_addr1


from db_name.carrier, db_name.customer

join db_name.location as loc_carr on vats.carrier.location_id=loc_carr.location_id

join db_name.location as loc_cust on vats.customer.location_id=loc_cust.location_id

Comment: Question:  Is `vats.carrier` the same table as `db_name.carrier`?  Also, you should use "explicit" join syntax in your FROM clause.  How are those two tables related ( `carrier` and `customer`)?

Comment: Yes, vats is db_name.  Carrier and customer tables both reference the location table using location_id.

Comment: Yes, but how do `carrier` and `customer` relate to each other?  Is there a `carrier_id` in each table?

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a guess that there is a column named something like `carrier_id` that can be used to join the `carrier` and `customer` tables. Given that assumption, try this:

```
select 
     loc_carr.address1 as carr_addr1
   , loc_cust.address1 as cust_addr1

from vats.carrier  as a

join vats.customer as b
  on b.carrier_id=a.carrier_id

join vats.location as loc_carr 
  on loc_carr.location_id=a.location_id

join vats.location as loc_cust 
  on loc_cust.location_id=b.location_id
```

Notice the use of aliases for the table references to make things easier to read.  Also note how I'm using explicit SQL join syntax (instead of listing tables separated by commas).

Answer (score 1):

@Bob Duell has the solution for your problem. To understand better why this error is produced, notice that in the `FROM` clause, you "join" tables using both explicit `JOIN` syntax and the implicit joins with comma: `,` which is (almost) equivalent to a `CROSS JOIN`. The precedence however of `JOIN` is stronger than the comma `,` operator. So, that part is parsed like this:

```
FROM 
  ( db_name.carrier )
  , 
  (   ( db_name.customer
      JOIN db_name.location AS loc_carr 
          ON carrier.location_id = loc_carr.location_id      -- this line
      )                                                      -- gives the error
    JOIN join db_name.location AS loc_cust 
        ON customer.location_id = loc_cust.location_id
  )
```

In the mentioned line above, the `vats.carrier.location_id` throws the error, as there is no `carrier` table in that scope (inside that parenthesis).

Comment: Bob, thank you so much for your time and information.  I need to step back and really look at my query and probably start from scratch.  It's actually bigger and more complicated and in simplifying to post I think I left out pertinent info.  I will use your info going forward and will probably posting again.  Thanks again Bob!